# Sheet copy error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following problem. I write a macro that copies a sheet from one workbook to another. Howebver, at the line with the copy destination I receive an "Application defined or object defined error" I tested the code with another new workboos and it works,but not with the workbook in which I am trying to implement it.

```
Dim x As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("S:\INM\MME9EG\Zahlenwerk MMA2EG Equities\DHN\DHN_Europa.xls")

Workbooks("DHN_Europa.xls").Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1")
```

Comment: does `Sheets("DHN Europe 799026")` worksheet _always_ belong to the workbook your macro resides in? And is that code you're showing following some `On Error....` statement?

Comment: would you mind answering my question? thank you

Comment: Yes the sheet is in the workbook, where the code is. And this is the whole code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WHOLE point of using a workbook variable is to 
replace `Workbooks("DHN_Europa.xls")` but the variable name,
here `x` (btw, try to have more explicit variable names, it'll be easier! ;) )

---

As this is a `xls` file, **you may only have about 65k rows, and yet you try to copy more than that!**

```
Dim x As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("S:\INM\MME9EG\Zahlenwerk MMA2EG Equities\DHN\DHN_Europa.xls")

x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV60000").Copy _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1")
```

Comment: I have already tried this. However it does not work. The sheets exist.

Comment: The error is on the the `x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy _` line and it is  "Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: @AntonPetrov : Is there a sheet named `Bericht_799026` in the workbook you are opening? Because there isn't much that could throw an error like this... Or... As this is a `xls` file, **you may only have about 65k rows, and yet you try to copy more than that!** try the 2nd proposition of the code!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Dim x As Workbook

Set x = Workbooks.Open("S:\INM\MME9EG\Zahlenwerk MMA2EG Equities\DHN\DHN_Europa.xls")

x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
```

*Of course, you need to make sure sheets with those names exist*

Comment: The sheets exist. but the proposed solution does not work.

Comment: Perhaps you need to show us more/all of your code then because both answers provided would not usually throw errors

Comment: @AntonPetrov It is good advise CallumDA gave you to separate copy and paste actions, thus you can pinpoint the error source better. So specify which line fails now, and error text as well.

Comment: The error is on the `x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("B4:IV150000").Copy ` line and it is "Application defined or object defined error"

Comment: @AntonPetrov Are you sure you use code from **this** answer, and not from R3uK's answer?

Comment: @AntonPetrov Then go to IV150000 cell. Try to execute line : `x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("IV150000").Select`. If it fails, try `x.Sheets("Bericht_799026").Range("IV65300").Select`. Post results here.

Answer (score 2):

it could be an Excel version issue, where version older then 2007 have 65k or so maximum rows number

try with

```
With Workbooks.Open("S:\INM\MME9EG\Zahlenwerk MMA2EG Equities\DHN\DHN_Europa.xls").Sheets("Bericht_799026")
    Intersect(.UsedRange, .Range("B4:IV4").Resize(.Rows.count - 3)).Copy _
            ThisWorkbook.Sheets("DHN Europe 799026").Range("A1")
End With
```

Comment: the same problem. Is it possible that smt is generally wrong with the workbooks?

Comment: I see that it hit you too!^^

Comment: @R3uK, yes, it's been after following a famous Sherlock Holmes _adage_

Comment: @R3uK, to bad not always the fastest wins!

Comment: Not always, but in that case, I did!^^ Your edit 15:44:37, my comment 15:43:29! ;) Until next time! :)

Comment: @R3uK, my edit is 15:38:34. No wait: my answer was that, while my edit was as you say.

Comment: Yup, I double checked before commenting with the times! But as always, your answer is pretty neat! ;) I'll try to be more inspired too next time! ;)

Comment: @R3uK, please next time take at least some 1 minute and 9 seconds to get more inspired!:)

Comment: Haha! When I'll have got passed the 10k rep, I promise to be slower! ;)